# How to disable selecting all my DIV's text with JQuery when I'm trying to select it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some DIVs i.e.:

```
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv1"> text1 </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv2"> text2 </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv3"> text3 </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv4"> text4 </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv5"> text5 </div>
```

It aligns in one row. I want to select some divs by capturing mouseDown, mouseOver and mouseUp events (looks like dragging my mouse from one div to the next one). I can code it. Also I can color its background to any color. It's easy. But when I try to "select" my divs the text on it also selects but I don't want to see that behaviour. I suppose it's default browser behaviour when we select the text on the page. How to avoid selecting of the text?

Comment: @casraf, thanks man! That's exactly what I need!

Comment: No problem, good luck